# Deenergizing Inductor

Tags: voltage, capacitor, current, inductor

I am reading through "Practical Electronics for Inventors" and I came upon a chapter about deenergizing inductor. I understand the concept that when you cut the current going into inductor, it will generate high voltage drop, since dI/dt goes to infinity. How come this is not an issue when the inductor "starts"? The voltage drop should be the same, right? Why this isn't an issue with capacitor? When we "turn" it on/off, there should be infinite current (minus internal resistance) according to laws. Shouldn't high current be a bigger problem than high voltage? What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

Think of inductors and capacitors as complimentary components.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fidPWU.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1.*

- (a) The inductor current is limited at start so no problem at switch on as it will rise more slowly than an equivelant DC resistor would. As you have identified, the problem is at switch off.
- (b) The capacitor is the opposite. There is a big problem at switch on as it behaves as a short-circuit so current is only limited by any inherent resistance in the circuit. At switch off there is no problem.
- (c) The solution for the inductor is to maintain current after switch-off using the snubber diode.
- (d) The standard solution for capacitors is to limit the charge with a series resistor. This may be bridged out when the voltage has reached a certain level. (This is done in high-powered switched-mode power-supplies or variable frequency drives, for example.)

Answer (score 0):

When you turn off what makes an inductor to have some energy in a field, you must cut off the current. Of course the current doesn't stop immediately, because the inductor generates as much voltage as it needs to have some path where current can go on, altough decaying. Obviously you already knew it - the suddenly rising voltage is called inductive peak.

In reverse case the faster you want to rise current in an inductor, the higher voltage you need. The proportionality factor is called inductance. 1 volt causes current rising speed 1A/one second if the inductance is 1 henry.

When you turn off what makes a capacitor to store energy in a field, you must short circuit the voltage. Of course the voltage doesn't fall immediately, but gradually. The capacitor generates as high current as is needed to retain a gradually decaying voltage.

In reverse case the faster you want to rise the voltage in a capacitor, the higher current you need. The proportionality factor is called capacitance. If you charge a capacitor with 1A current and that causes the voltage rise 1 volt/one second, then the capacitance is 1 farad.

Check also this case: [How does the inductor ''really'' induce voltage?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/282053/how-does-the-inductor-really-induce-voltage)

Answer (score 0):

> I understand the concept that when you cut the current going into
>   inductor, it will generate high voltage drop, since dI/dt goes to
>   infinity. How come this is not an issue when the inductor "starts"?

The same formula applies to both: -

$$V=L\cdot\dfrac{di}{dt}$$

- When you apply a moderate voltage you get a moderate ramp rate of current
- When you apply a high voltage you get a high ramp rate of current

When you disconnect that voltage (and I don't mean short it or reduce it to zero), the rate of change of current is massive (and negative) and, as should be expected, you get a massive reverse voltage.

If instead of disconnecting the voltage you reduced it instantly to zero, you'd get the same speed ramp but this time falling to zero.

For a capacitor you use currents instaed of voltages and you see exactly the same thing: -

- When you apply a moderate current you get a moderate ramp rate of voltage
- When you apply a high current you get a high ramp rate of voltage
- If you shorted a charged capacitor you get a massive pulse of current because you've engineered a massive change in voltage across its terminals.