# Current Probe with 1mA precision

Tags: current, probe

I've designed this circuit for a 1 mili amp precision current probe, what change should I apply to it?

[image: schematic]

Comment: If you've designed it then presumably you have designed it against a series of requirements so, given this, YOU are in the best position to think of changes.

Comment: Apply no changes if you have got the wanted functionality, precision and accuracy. If something is missing you should ask for it. Our abilities to see what is wanted is quite limited.

Comment: You must define ALL SPECS. Don't assume anyone knows. Normally R sense is 50mV @  max current for a defined temp rise, then amplified to max range.  Your BJT Buffer is not a uniform pulse source impedance (f) nor is the BW of the signal defined.

Comment: Always define all characteristics of input and output expected.

Comment: it's a closed loop current sense circuit,current is sensed by ratiometric hall sensor P(2), then the main signal will be amplified with U2, then applied to the class ab amplifier which is fed to a compensation coil as a feedback(to make flux zero), the problem is I don't know how my feedback port works and how should I bias my push pull amplifier,(haven't passed linear control yet).

Comment: Add all that information into the question so all the information is in one place. "mili amp" (in your question title and in the post) should be "milliamp" or "mA" as in the SI standards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no spec of the wanted functionality, accuracy nor precision, only some contradictions can be shown.

There's a 100pF capacitor C1. Only sub-microsecond pulses get through it undisturbed because there's about 10kOhm loading. Those pulses are well beyond the useful frequency range of your U1.  You shouldn't assume the amp is automatically a well working low pass filter and a precision amp at the same time. The result is very difficult to predict.

It could work if part P4 had high enough inductance AND the drive for it were redesigned to eliminate the inductive kickback.

ADD due the given details:

Part P4 obviously is the inductor which should neutralize the existing magnetic field in the test point. Neutralization is possible if the coil produces a field which has exactly right direction and the field to be neutralized doesn't change too fast.

You have class AB amp which can have whatever current through from Vcc to GND directly through the output transistors. The lower transistor is useless because without negative supply your circuit can push only one directional current through the coil.

You have no attempt to kill possible high voltage peak that occur if the feeding circuit suddenly tries to stop the current of the coil. I guess sooner or later something will be destroyed.

You have no actual controller which searches the total zero field current for your coil. Designing such controller needs some knowledge of the control theory.

Comment: 1-the circuit should be able to measure DC current between 500 to 600 mili amps with a precision of 1 mili amps. I've adopted it from the design of DRV421.
2-I've added the filter part cause I though maybe RF signals will affect it,(don't blame if I'm totall noob!),so should I remove it?or...?
3-I can increase the inductance by changing my compensation coil turns of thickness,I'm clueless about the Inductive kickback part! eliminate it? why and how?

Comment: 4-was it even logical to use class ab amplifier? I could feed my Vss to it instead of GND.
5-how the high voltage peak could happen?what should I do about it?
6-I'm completely clueless about the last part, I know somethings about feedback as I'learned them in Signal and systems AND in my Electronics 2, but the designing the controller...! Would appreciate any guidance sir!

Comment: If it's not possible to design a controller with my current knowledge I'll appreciate any source!

Comment: @MohamadGholizadeh Add to the question all details you have given in comments. Read at least this about how inductors generate voltage: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/282053/how-does-the-inductor-really-induce-voltage

Comment: I mean wow! the effort I'd put to this part is comparably nothing to the part I should make...
I got it but how should I neutralize it?

Comment: sir please guide md, I really need your help!

Comment: @MohamadGholizadeh start a chat in this site and invite me to it. We can see there if I can say something useful. These comments are not intended for discussions. Do it before this case gets closed as "unclear or too wide"!

Comment: I'm trying to make one but beside "show frozen rooms" "create new room" doesn't appear!!!

Comment: @MohamadGholizadeh A diode can redirect the inductive current back to the power supply or dissipate it. The latter is the simplest way. People who use relays or electric magnets generally have flyback diodes in parallel with the coils if there's only one directional current. Bipolar current need more complex circuits.