# What happens to the inductor when the current stops suddenly?

Tags: inductor

I have this circut:

[image]

Where Rx is the resistance of the inductor.

What will happen to the inductor if the current stops suddenly?

I said that the inductor will "burn" because the currents will be 0, however my friend says that the inductor will act as a source (which is right, but I think this case is different because the current stops suddenly, and not decrease slowly, the voltage will be higher.)

Comment: What does a lot of dI/dt imply?

Comment: Do you mean L=di/dt?

Comment: Where is the inductor in the circuit ? How is the current stopped suddenly in the above circuit ? Are the volt meter and ammeter shown ideal ?

Comment: R represent the resistane of the inductor. yes, the V and A meters are ideal

Comment: L=/=di/dt... V = L * di/dt where V is the voltage across the inductor and L is the inductance. If current instantly goes from say 1A to 0A, your di/dt is 1A / 0s which is infinite (undefined really), so your inductor will develop infinite voltage to keep that 1A flowing.

Comment: @Stiddily and that means that the inductor will burn itself?

Comment: What you should learn from all comments and answer(s) here is: **you cannot suddenly stop the current in an inductor**. Compare it to the situation with a capacitor, you cannot **instantly** charge or discharge a capacitor, there is **always** some time involved. Same with the current through an inductor, some time is needed to change the current, it cannot be done instantly.

Comment: This old case has something about it https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/282053/how-does-the-inductor-really-induce-voltage.  Your voltmeter can enjoy its last portion of electricity if you have big enough energy stored in the inductor and you succeed to break the input current fast enough.

Comment: Why so many downvotes though?

Answer (score 3):

If you suddenly disconnect the battery from the coil in your circuit, the voltage across the coil will **rise** as the inductor tries to keep the current flowing.

If you use a switch to interrupt the current, then you will get a spark that jumps the contacts of the switch.

It you use a transistor to interrupt the current, the voltage will rise until it is higher than the breakdown voltage of the transistor.  The transistor will conduct and discharge the coil, and the transistor will be destroyed.

If the coil is large enough and your (mechanical) switch is fast enough, then the coil won't be able to discharge through the spark.  The voltage will continue rising until the coil can either discharge through the air (if there are bare connections close enough together,) or that the voltage gets so high that the voltage between the layers of the coil is high enough for the coil to discharge through the insulation on the wires in the coil windings.  A discharge through the coil itself has a good chance of damaging the insulation to the point that the coil will short out and burn up the next time you try to use it.

---

I've never personally had a coil breakdown like that.

I have had one hold a high voltage for several seconds after I disconnected it from a low voltage (maybe 12V.)  The zap I got when I touched the terminals was painful, and I was very glad that it only went through my finger.  I think if it had gone hand to hand that I wouldn't be here writing about it.